# Issues with admin panel

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

Hi I wanted to show a **form to the admin** which is going to fetch some data from the database (more than one table), so that the admin can get more information of user in the same form.

So how I can add a template to admin interface in Django and display it on the main home page.

Comment: See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend admin templates, for example admin/base.html.